Upload page with restricts(users can not see other's uploads)
How can i setup a Sharepoint page, where the users can upload just once,
but can not see others uploads?
Other goal is that if they visit the upload url
its automatically create their folders with their name and institute name,
is it possible to specify such as link(send the parameters in the url)?
